# retrieving all records(documents) of Couchbase

Tags: node.js, couchbase

I am using node.js and looking for a way to get all documents of a specific bucket of couchbase. Is there any solution without having a loop and incremental index ? I know I can make an atomic key and later on using it via a loop to retrieve all data.But I need a function which returns all documents. Is there any function which 'at least' return me the number of documents already exist in bucket?

Answer (score 2):

I've had this question before me as well, as per Couchbase engineering team its not possible without having a view. So I ended up having a naming convention for a view that should be present in every bucket that I want to have list of ALL keys.

I call it "Keys" and my map function like this:

```
function (doc, meta) {
  emit(meta.id, null);
}
```

So then on my client I can iterate over all the documents in the bucket...since I know all the keys.

Another alternative is to use [N1QL](http://www.couchbase.com/communities/n1ql) to get all the keys. THis is a new query language introduced in Couchbase 3. So you can write a query like this to return all documents keys:

```
SELECT META().id AS id 
FROM your_bucket_name
```

Or you can return all documents themselves:

```
SELECT * 
FROM your_bucket_name
```

Check [Node.js and N1QL](http://blog.couchbase.com/nodejs-and-n1ql) for additional information.

Comment: Thanks for your help. I knew N1QL I want to use it. But there is an error. Would you please tell your idea about this post :http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26044397/n1ql-and-node-on-couchbase

Answer (score 0):

There is now a range scan feature to retrieve all documents or all ids in a collection. See [Couchbase retrieving all documents from all collections in scope](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74827901/couchbase-retrieving-all-documents-from-all-collections-in-scope)