# Node JS Couchbase Module - How to Get All Keys of a Bucket?

Tags: node.js, couchbase

I installed the Node Couchbase client module using `npm install couchbase`. How to get the all keys (or documents) data of a bucket?

For example, I have a bucket called `users`, and each document is a username of each individual user, so I want to retrieve the information of all of them?

Thanks

Comment: possible duplicate of [retrieving all records(documents) of Couchbase](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26017989/retrieving-all-recordsdocuments-of-couchbase)

Answer (score 0):

You have two ways to go about it, depending on your Couchbase server and how bullet-proof this needs to be:

- The 'traditional' way is to use a view: its a function that you define on the server and it returns sets of documents. The view can return just the document names (and then you can use a [getMulti() bulk operation](http://developer.couchbase.com/documentation/server/4.0/sdks/node-2.0/bulk-operations.html) to get all of the documents) or even the documents themselves, as the response of the view.
- If you're running a recent version of Couchbase AND don't mind experimenting with beta tech, you could try N1QL ("Nickel"): its like SQL for Couchbase. Wouldn't use it for production, but its just a side project this could be a lot easier.

Not sure how useful the links below are (I dont use Couch with Node.JS), but they're probably worth reading:

http://lukeramsey.io/views-in-couchbase

http://blog.couchbase.com/nodejs-and-n1ql

Comment: N1QL will be part of 4.0 which is in release candidate now and going GA soon. So depending on the go live time line of the project and use case, this could be an option.