# Couchbase retrieving all documents from all collections in scope

Tags: couchbase

Is it possible to retrieve all documents from all collections in a scope without N1QL query. Because of huge volume we are trying to avoid index creation hence can not execute N1QL. The cluster where such data is being placed is archive store and will not be accessed frequently.

Comment: Checkout DCP or connectors

Comment: Thanks for reply would you please share more details?

Answer (score 2):

The new KV range scan feature will do this - scan() method.

https://docs.couchbase.com/sdk-api/couchbase-java-client-3.4.1/com/couchbase/client/java/Collection.html

Prior to that, create a view to get all the keys.

https://forums.couchbase.com/t/how-to-extract-in-a-list-all-keys-from-a-bucket/856/1

Then iterate through the keys with collection.get(id)

Comment: Michael Reiche Thanks for reply. So, prior to couchbase java client 3.4.1  there is no possibility right for getting all documents from collection without N1QL?

Comment: You also need supported server of RangeScans (which is  part of future releases). Your best option is as Michael mentioned use map reduce views (index and n1ql is not required) get all the keys and use SDK get the documents.

Comment: Thanks for suggestion but it will require to create primary index right?

Answer (score 1):

map-reduce view does not require indexes. Neither does range scan.

Answer (score 0):

In my project in order to get rid of indices we store keys in related documents, and access everything only by keys. Only small subset of documents were indexed to hold all database keys.